# XSLT - adding numbers based on a node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml like this,

```
<doc>
    <sec>
        <table>
            <footnote>fn1</footnote>
            <p>
                <footnote>fn2</footnote>
            </p>
            <footnote>fn3</footnote>
        </table>
        <table>
            <p>
                <footnote>fn4</footnote>
                <footnote>fn5</footnote>
            </p>
            <footnote>fn6</footnote>
            <footnote>fn7</footnote>
            <footnote>fn8</footnote>
        </table>
    </sec>
    <sec>
        <table>
            <footnote>fn9</footnote>
            <footnote>fn10</footnote>
            <footnote>fn11</footnote>
        </table>
    </sec>
</doc>
```

I need to number the footnotes is such that it every time should start with 1 within the tables, I'm using XSLT for the transformation.

SO expected output is,

```
<doc>
    <sec>
        <table>
            <footnote>1<s/>fn1</footnote>
            <p>
                <footnote>2<s/>fn2</footnote>
            </p>
            <footnote>3<s/>fn3</footnote>
        </table>
        <table>
            <p>
                <footnote>1<s/>fn4</footnote>
                <footnote>2<s/>fn5</footnote>
            </p>
            <footnote>3<s/>fn6</footnote>
            <footnote>4<s/>fn7</footnote>
            <footnote>5<s/>fn8</footnote>
        </table>
    </sec>
    <sec>
        <table>
            <footnote>1<s/>fn9</footnote>
            <footnote>2<s/>fn10</footnote>
            <footnote>3<s/>fn11</footnote>
        </table>
    </sec>
</doc>
```

I've tried to use `position()` function and I've tried to calculate using count() function but could not figure out a way for this.

```
<xsl:template match="footnote">
        <xsl:variable name="count-pre" select="count(preceding::footnote)-count(ancestor::table/footnote)"/>

        <footnote>
            <xsl:value-of select="$count-pre"/>
            <s/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </footnote>
    </xsl:template>
```

Can anyone suggest me a way to do this using XSLT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <xsl:template match="footnote">
        <footnote>
            <xsl:number from="table" level="any"/>
            <s/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </footnote>
    </xsl:template>
```

See transformation at http://xsltransform.net/jxN8NpF